# How to use Ruby on Rails to store (post) files and other binaries in Parse.com using their REST API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest

Can you help me figure out how to use Ruby on Rails to store (post) files and other binaries in Parse.com using their REST API?

After trying to get it to work with net/http, rest-client and curl (gem) the results are less understanding and more errors...

See: https://parse.com/docs/rest#files
for an example using the curl command (sending PNG)

Basically it comes down to:
- doing a POST from Ruby on Rails
- containing the special Parse.com headers (X-Parse-Application-Id and X-Parse-REST-API-Key)
- with the binary data of the file as the body/payload
- to HTTPS: https://api.parse.com/1/files/testimage.png